# window.print not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing

```
function CallPrint() {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById('<%= pnlDelete.ClientID %>');
        var winPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        winPrint.document.write("<h3>Summary</h3><br />" + prtContent.innerHTML);
        winPrint.document.close();
        winPrint.focus();
        winPrint.print();
        winPrint.close();
    }
```

I have a need where I have to print contents of a div. I am using above code to do so. It is working fine in IE but does nothing in Firefox. Am I missing something here that needs to be done in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of opening a new window without any URL, I opened this page in the window and accessed the contents of the pnlSummary from the opened window via window.opener object –

```
function CallPrint() {
    var winPrint = window.open('Print.aspx', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
}
```

On Print.aspx page I used this function –

```
function Print() {
    var prtContent = "<h3>Summary</h3>" + window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_cphContent_pnlSummary').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("printDiv").innerHTML = prtContent;
    window.print();
    window.opener.focus();
    window.close(); }
```

and called it on body onload.

```
<body onload="Print();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="printDiv">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[This](http://utkarshpuranik.com/2010/01/12/window-print-not-working-in-firefox/) is working fine in both IE and Firefox.

Comment: sorry? which is the way used to solve the problem? you didn't select an answer. (e.g. your answer should have been a comment added to the answer another user gave that was correct... and mark theirs as correct)

Comment: none of the responses provided helped me resolve my problem, I myself was working on it in-between and found a solution which I blogged and provided a link here and marked it as answer.

Comment: Consider putting more information in this answer so that people don't have to leave SO to get the information they need.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... your code seems to work fine for me, on Firefox 3.5 (Windows).
It's possible that are something wrong on your pnlDelete.ClientID? 
Your javascript code is rendered well on the page?

Anyway I suggest you to use jQuery + a print plugin like [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint).

Comment: +1 because I'm not willing to reinvent the wheel. Use libraries to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure your panel has something. My guess is `prtContent` is undefined

Try this:

```
function CallPrint() {
    var prtContent = document.getElementById('<%= pnlDelete.ClientID %>');

    if (prtContent) {
        var winPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        winPrint.document.write("<h3>Summary</h3><br />" + prtContent.innerHTML);
        winPrint.document.close();
        winPrint.focus();
        winPrint.print();
        winPrint.close();
    }
    else {
        alert('No summary available for printing');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout()` function for loading the page. The example is given bellow link.

http://oraclehappy2help.blogspot.in/2012/09/child-window-printing-problem-solution.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Instead of using windows.print(); use  var t=setTimeout(function(){win.window.print();},5000);  if you connection is slow then increase the time. I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use JS Printer Setup https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/"

which is Fire fox Depended addon most usefulladdon In web-app Kisok in Firefox to select printer

attached some example for attached printer and local printer it may help you to build without print dialog.

```js
function EB_Print(printType) {
 try{
  var printerType = printType; // type of the Print Code : network 
  // Default Printer Configuring
  var Default_printer = "Canon MG2500 series";
  
  /** local Printer configuring via Network
   ** Config teh Local server use \\\\ to get \\ 
   **/
  var Organizer_Printer = "\\\\network\\Canon LBP2900";
  
  jsPrintSetup.setPrinter(Default_printer);
  jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(true);// withoud dialog 
  
  /** alert(jsPrintSetup.getPrintersList()); // Debugger for the attached Printers list
    alert(jsPrintSetup.getPrinter());   // get the set printer Option
  **/
 // id network is selected It will print the page in network
  if(printerType == 'network'){
   jsPrintSetup.setPrinter(Organizer_Printer);
  }
   jsPrintSetup.print(); // Print the page
   
  
 }catch (e) {
  // TODO: handle exception
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a jquery plugin...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/PrintArea