# FireFox Image Printing Issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing, cross-browser

I have the following code which prints any HTML loaded in to popup window. I am printing multiple invoices at once using the following code. As you could see in the code, when the window is opened the print window is also opened.  The HTML is the ‘content’ parameter.

```
function( content ){
    var invoice_window = window.open( '', 'print', 'width=500,height=400,fullscreen=0,location=0,menubar=1,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0' );



    invoice_window.document.body.innerHTML = content;                   
    invoice_window.print();
    invoice_window.close();

}
```

The HTML content included some images (not background images) as well. This is working as expected in IE, but not in FireFox. The problem in FF is the images are not printing, just the ‘alt’ attribute value is printing in the image area.

Things I have tested so far;

I commented out invoice_window.close();Then, I can print the page (the window opened with the HTML content) using the browser’s (FireFox) print option. Then, the images are printing in FF.

Any help would be much appreciated. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the opened page to actually load before printing.

Comment: I actually did. Also, used setTimeout(). No difference.

Comment: Also, used the solution suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999108/window-print-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record: I had similar issue: IFrame did not loaded the images, even if I waited a fairly long timeout before 'print'.

The solution in my case was that firefox needed a  in order to orient itself in case of generated content and relative images.

Comment: Firefox needed a what? The answer is missing a word, there.