# can we develop a koisk page in php

Tags: php, html, kiosk

I need to create a simple kiosk page having 2 external links.I don't have any knowledge how to work on it.I am working on php so is it possible to do with PHP/HTML or else I need to go for any other language.

Comment: There's no reason why not, it's perfectly possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Let's test this with a little example index.php in the root folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <span><?php echo "This text was generated with PHP"; ?></span>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible on chrome and firefox.

i worked in kiosk php by firefox so i can give you some details how i done.

Firefox:

used this plugin 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mkiosk/

and used for silent print i used this plugin
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

this is how i enabled it in Firefox
[window.print not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999108/window-print-not-working-in-firefox/32264059#32264059)

Chrome:

Inbuilt you have Kisok mode so you can enable it.